# I want to Split string Using Computed column in views AX2012

Tags: view, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, computed-field

I am using Computed columns in views. I have a string stored in one column of a table. I want to split that string using Computed Columns.

eg.

```
ColumnA =  0001^93.2
```

Resullt:

```
ColumnB = 0001
ColumnC = 93.2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [CHARINDEX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173376(v=sql.110).aspx) and [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748(v=sql.110).aspx).

```cs
public static server str compColB()
{
    str result;

    result = strFmt("SUBSTRING(%1, 0, CHARINDEX(N'^', %1)"
        , SysComputedColumn::returnField(tableNum(SourceTable), 'viewDataSoure', fieldStr(ViewName, ColumnA))
    );


    return result;
}


public static server str compColC()
{
    str result;

    result = strFmt("SUBSTRING(%1, CHARINDEX(N'^', %1) + 1, 9999"
        , SysComputedColumn::returnField(tableNum(SourceTable), 'viewDataSoure', fieldStr(ViewName, ColumnA))
    );


    return result;
}
```